# Get human/defined name in rails group_label_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a grouped_select in Rails using 2 models. The models themselves have names Foo::Bar and Foo::Baz. How do I get the optgroup labels to be Bar and Baz instead of Foo::Bar and Foo::Baz?

```
 <%= f.input :global_superzone,  collection: [Foo::Bar, Foo::Baz], as: :grouped_select,
 group_method: :all, group_label_method: :model_name,
 label_method: :name, value_method: :to_global_id , :include_blank => false %>
```

It's the group_label_method: :model_name that I need to alter but if I put anything else in there it throws an error e.g. :model_name.human. I also tried to add a method to the models but that failed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a module:

```
module HumanName
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def human_name
      model_name.human
    end
  end
end
```

and include it into every model we are interested in:

```
class Foo::Bar
  include HumanName
end

# etc.
```

And lastly update `group_label_method` option:

```
group_label_method: :human_name
```